# Only Show Comment in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, comments

I am looking for a way to only show the comments posted in wordpress.

My main goal is to turn the wordpress CMS into a site like fmylife.com. The basic principle is allowing anyone to post anonymously (without having a post to comment on), and then the comments need to be moderated by the admin.

If there is an easier solution to doing this, then I'm open to hearing that as well.  The only thing I don't want to do is get the fmyscript clone.  I've tried that and don't like it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the [buddypress](http://buddypress.org/) plugin wherein users can register and post. Just disable all other components except activity feed and make your homepage as a static activity feed page (configurable in the settings).

Comment: Hey Same... thanks for the advince...If there is another way in which users don't have to register, that would be best.  The nature of the site works better if they're anonymous.